# Trying to submit a node add form via AJAX but failing

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I'm simply trying to submit a node add form via AJAX:

```
function input_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'page_node_form':
      $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Submit'),
        '#ajax' => array(
            'wrapper' => 'apple-node-form',
            'callback' => 'node_add_callback',
            'method' => 'replace',
            'effect' => 'fade'
        )
      );
      break;
  }
  return;
}

function node_add_callback(){
  $node = new stdClass();
  $node->type = 'page';
  return drupal_get_form('node_form', $node);
}
```

`input_form_alter()` DOES get called. And when I click the submit button, I even see the standard ajax gif and "Please wait" message. The gif and wait message then disappear, as expected. However, no new node has actually been created.

Comment: So the person is on the node add screen, and when they hit submit you want it to submit the form using AJAX?  You might want to add a drupal_set_message("node_add_callback was called"); to the top of your node_add_callback to make sure it's getting called.  My head is getting wobbly trying to understand the goal of this one...

Comment: Yes, node_add_callback is getting called. Not sure why creating content via AJAX is such a strange goal. It's about to happen when I click the add comment button to the right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it. The problem was this code:

```
  $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
    '#ajax' => array(
        'wrapper' => 'apple-node-form',
        'callback' => 'node_add_callback',
        'method' => 'replace',
        'effect' => 'fade'
    )
  );
```

This overwrites the `$form['actions']['submit']` array that already existed, recreating it with the values I specified. Since all I wanted to do was add an AJAX submission, the following code should replace the above:

```
    $form['actions']['submit']['#ajax'] = array(
        'wrapper' => 'apple-node-form',
        'callback' => 'node_add_callback',
        'method' => 'replace',
        'effect' => 'fade'
    );
```

In other words, we're just adding an `#ajax` item to the already created `$form['actions']['submit']` array.